# How do I declare the topic of a KafkaListener in Scala using a property value

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have a simple Kafka/Scala project that creates a producer. Now I am trying to create the consumer, however, when I use the following code...

```
@Service
class KafkaService @Autowired()(producer: KafkaTemplate[String, Array[Byte]]){

  @Value("${spring.kafka.topic}") val topic : String = null

  def sendMessage(msg: String): Unit = {
    System.out.println(s"Writing the message $msg to the topic ${this.topic}")
    producer.send(topic, msg.getBytes());
  }

  @KafkaListener(id="test", topics="${this.topic}")
  def consume(record: ConsumerRecord[String, String]): Unit = {
    System.out.println(s"Consumed Strinsg Message : ${record.value()}")
  }

}
```

I get the following error...

```
[ERROR] ...\service\KafkaService.scala:26: error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : String("${this.topic}")
[ERROR]  required: Array[String]
[ERROR]   @KafkaListener(id="test", topics="${this.topic}")
```

What am I missing?

I also tried the following...

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfiguration{
    ...
    @Value("${spring.kafka.topic}")
    public String topic;
    ...
}
@Service
class KafkaService @Autowired()(producer: KafkaTemplate[String, Array[Byte]], config: CommonConfiguration){

  def sendMessage(msg: String): Unit = {
    val topics : Array[String] = config.getTopics();
    println(s"Writing the message $msg ${topics.mkString(" ")}")
    producer.send(config.topic, msg.getBytes());
  }

  @KafkaListener(id="test", topics="#{config.topic.split(',')}")
  def consume(record: ConsumerRecord[String, String]): Unit = {
    System.out.println(s"Consumed Strinsg Message : ${record.value()}")
  }

}
```

Still no luck but the console log on the producer is getting the right value.

Comment: Looks to be related to this right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065408/how-do-i-use-spring-expression-language-with-scala

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you need a Array[String] type for topics whereas you have supplied a String type. You would need to convert the topics string into an array.

The annotations looks very similar to Spring where you can do something like

```
@Value("#{'${kafka.topic}'.split(',')}")
```

Comment: A appreciate you trying to help but there is a reason I specified Scala in the title. I tried that way and it isn't working.

Comment: The gist of my answer is that you need a way to convert the String type into Array[String]. What I also see is that the kafka listener is reading the value "${this.topic}" and not the actual value of the topic.If this was the case, then you would see the error message as String("topicName") instead of String("${this.topic}").

Comment: Gist doesn't help me I already tried this based on other questions. I need the actual value. See update.

Comment: It looks like this is using SpEL which Scala doesn't support. So this is not a good answer when I confirm that Scala doesn't support it I will add link but I will also need to down vote.

Comment: Per your original code, could you try
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{__listener.topic}")
This is how we have used in spring kafka (java). It may or may not work in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

```
@KafkaListener(id="scala", topics=Array("#{'${spring.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}"))
```

for more info see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323732/why-does-requestmapping-annotation-accept-string-parameter-in-java-but-not-in-s) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065408/how-do-i-use-spring-expression-language-in-an-annotation-with-scala)