# How do I use Spring Expression Language for an Array in an annotation with Scala

Tags: spring, scala, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-el

I have a simple Scala project that looks like this...

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfiguration{
    ...
    @Value("${spring.kafka.topic}")
    public String topic;
    ...
}
@Service
class KafkaService @Autowired()(producer: KafkaTemplate[String, Array[Byte]], config: CommonConfiguration){

  def sendMessage(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(s"Writing the message $msg ${config.topic}")
    producer.send(config.topic, msg.getBytes());
  }

  @KafkaListener(id="test", topics="#{'${spring.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}")
  def consume(record: ConsumerRecord[String, String]): Unit = {
    System.out.println(s"Consumed Strinsg Message : ${record.value()}")
  }

}
```

This gives me the error...

```
KafkaService.scala:26: error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : String("#{\'${spring.kafka.topic}\'.split(\',\')}")
[ERROR]  required: Array[String]
[ERROR]   @KafkaListener(id="test", topics= "#{'${spring.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}")
```

I tried using `#{'${spring.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}` per [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/361#issuecomment-313200577) suggestion but I can't get it to work. The producer gets the topic just fine. How do I use Spring Expression Language with Scala?

Here is the working Java Version...

```
@Service
public class KafkaJavaService {
    @KafkaListener(id="test", topics="#{'${spring.kafka.topic}'.split(',')}")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record){
        System.out.println("Consumed String Message : "+record.value())
    }
}
```

Comment: The type of `topics` is `String[]`. I don't know scala; maybe it doesn't coerce a single String into a `String[]` within an annotation (unlike Java). `required: Array[String]`. In Java `topics = { "#{...}"  }` would work as well; I don't know the equivalent syntax for Scala. Spring does recursive analysis of the property (so it will flatten a `String[String[]]`).

Comment: Thanks for that I pretty much assumed all of that because but tried to keep the question simple. If you come across a way to do it please feel free to answer.

Comment: I updated to make a little clearer that the real issue is with using it in a Annotation context

Comment: Show the scala version with the `Array` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323732/why-does-requestmapping-annotation-accept-string-parameter-in-java-but-not-in-s), it looks like `topics = Array("...")` should work.

> Reading the `@RequestMapping` documentation : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html
>
> It accepts a String array parameter for its path mapping.
>
> So this works using java :
>
> `@RequestMapping("MYVIEW")`
>
> but in scala I need to use :
>
> `@RequestMapping(Array("MYVIEW"))`

The scala version makes sense as the annotation expects a String array. But why does above work in java, should it not give a compile time error ?

**EDIT**

> This is also not technically the same thing because the other way I could use a CSV. Even if the worked it would be a 1 string array unless the Array constructor does some fancyness.

It shouldn't make a difference; as I said, if an expression in an element of the `String[]` resolves to a `String[]`, we recursively break it apart (flatten it). See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/f44193e4dfd4a65fd89dd123ff24ff4b9b4d2709/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L514-L524) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/f44193e4dfd4a65fd89dd123ff24ff4b9b4d2709/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L633-L638).

Try setting a breakpoint in those methods; I don't have Scala installed otherwise I'd take a look.

Comment: I will try it but I don't think that will work because It will claim to need to be a constant

Comment: Also it does in fact work fine in Java, I just don't think Scala supports SpEL the same way.

Comment: This is also not technically the same thing because the other way I could use a CSV. Even if the worked it would be a 1 string array unless the Array constructor does some fancyness.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; edit your question to show the current state and what error you are getting now.

Comment: Just to confirm, Scala spec says an `Array(const)` is a constant, and JLS 9.7.3 for using string when array is expected for the value, in Java.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help let me try a couple of things. If it can handle CSV then I should be able to use it in my value annotation instead rt?